# 'Type missmatch' error when using StringChange in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I'm having troubles when trying to use **StringChange** / **StringChangeEx**. This code gives me the error "*Type missmatch*" on the line where I use **StringChange**:

```
function CustomSelectDirPageNextButtonClick(Sender: TWizardPage): Boolean;
var
  DirString: String;
begin
  Result := True;
  DirString := SetupMessage(msgDirExists);
  DirString := StringChange(DirString, '%1', WizardDirValue);
  // DirString := StringChangeEx(DirString, '%1', WizardDirValue, True);

  if MsgBox(DirString, mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDNO then
    Result := false;
  end;
end;
```

My obvious purpose is to replace the string "%1" with the value contained in WizardDirValue variable.

I'm working on Inno Setup v6.2.2 Unicode.

How do I fix this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`StringChange()`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchange) returns an `Integer` (the number of times a replacement was made). You try to assign that Integer to a string.

`StringChange()` modifies the string already, so you don't need to assign it.

Also note that the documentation says that this function is deprecated.

Comment: I'm stupid for haven't noticed that the return value type was a Integer. Thank you.

Comment: @ElektroStudios: no problem. Most languages have immutable strings, so it's natural to assign them to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The direct answer for the reason of the error that I was getting it is in @Thomas Weller answer. This answer is just to mention that I found the proper way or solution to do this it is using the [FmtMessage](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_fmtmessage) function:

```
  DirString := SetupMessage(msgDirExists);
  DirString := FmtMessage(DirString, [WizardDirValue]);

  MsgBox(DirString, mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2)
```